# Create Polygon using JGeometry

Tags: java, oracle, geometry, polygon, spatial

I have a table in oracle where I save SDO_Geometry elements as polygon:

```
SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2003, 
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1), 
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(100,80, 120,80, 140,60, 140,40, 120,20, 100,20, 80,40, 80,60
)
```

How can I create a JGeometry object which equals the above?
This is my current approach:

```
int[] elems = {1, 1003,1};
double[] coords = {100,80, 120,80, 140,60, 140,40, 120,20, 100,20, 80,40, 80,60};
JGeometry sdoGeometry = new JGeometry(JGeometry.GTYPE_POLYGON, someVariableIDontKnow, elems, coords);
```

But for some reason I need a parameter in the constructor and I don't know what the needed parameter is.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is the SRID, which indicates what reference system the co-ordiantes in parameter 4 relate to.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14373/oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html#JGeometry_int__int__int____double___

Comment: Please post your answer, rather than attach external links.